# Data Replication from Amazon RDS for MySQL to Amazon Aurora for PostgreSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-replication, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

We need to replicate data from an Amazon RDS (MySQL) databaes to an Aurora PostgreSQL database. Each database is on a different AWS account and region.

The data must be replicated in the PostgreSQL instance every 6 hours, so we need the guarantee that the data doesn't duplicate even if a field updated for a record.

Which method, tool, or design is better to do that? (Could be different to AWS.)

Comment: What do you mean by "the data doesn't duplicate even if a field updated for a record"?

Comment: Hi John, I mean, If one or several records were updated, I want to update those records in replica, don't duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could facilitate one of the following services provided by AWS:

1. [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)
2. [Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) supports:

- [Using an Amazon-Managed MySQL-Compatible Database as a Source for AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.AmazonManaged)
- [Using a PostgreSQL Database as a Target for AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.PostgreSQL.html)